# Last column jumping to the next row in ion-grid Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ion-grid

I am trying to create a footer with 5 buttons/icons. Actually I am trying to replicate a tab, but without using that function.
There is enough space to fit the 5 icons with teir label, however, for some reason in Android the last icon is jumping to the next row. I have been trying to play with the width and sizes but I could not obtain the desired result.

Any suggestion?

Long story short: I want that in Android the footer will be displayed as in Ios

Thanks

[image: Ios vs Android view]

```
<ion-footer>
 <ion-toolbar color="light">
  <ion-grid>
   <ion-row> 

    <ion-col>  
      <ion-tab-button >
        <ion-icon src="/assets/couple_on.svg"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Info</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>
    </ion-col> 

    <ion-col>  
      <ion-tab-button >
        <ion-icon src="/assets/rings_off.svg"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Donde</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>
    </ion-col> 

    <ion-col>  
      <ion-tab-button >
        <ion-icon src="/assets/church_off.svg"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Inicio</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>
    </ion-col> 

    <ion-col>
      <ion-tab-button >
        <ion-icon src="/assets/cake_off.svg"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Programa</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>
    </ion-col>

    <ion-col>
      <ion-tab-button >
        <ion-icon src="/assets/camera_off.svg"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Fotos</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>
     </ion-col>        
    </ion-row>
   </ion-grid>
  </ion-toolbar>
 </ion-footer>
```

Edit: When I translated to russian (longer words), and using the nowrap, the last icon was going away from the screen. I tried to reduce the size of the label, but still is not centered. Its annoying because I now it fits, as its seen in Ios:

[image]

EDIT 2: In was seeing it in the simulator and with your  correctios was ok.  However in the phone is still going away from the screen in the russian version, and in the spanish is not centered, there is more space on the left than on the right. 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y377b.jpg)[image]
[image]

Comment: I put the window in different monitor (Im working with 2 screens) and the visualization was ok. Then I realized that I had the zoom in Chrome at 125%. I changed to 100% and was ok. Good that I realized because it was driving me crazy not understanding was is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could force the row to not to wrap:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/row#row-attributes

But in this case, you need to handle smaller screen sizes as the columns won't "shrink down" automatically

```
<ion-footer>
 <ion-toolbar color="light">
  <ion-grid>
   <ion-row nowrap>
     ...        
    </ion-row>
   </ion-grid>
  </ion-toolbar>
 </ion-footer>
```

If you still lack space you can optimize it by:

a. removing padding (

- apply no-padding attribute to ion-grid, ion-row, ion-column
- or just add simple CSS rule

b. make svg smaller via size="small"

c. use Chrome Dev tools, select element and see which css you need to tackle to make it perfectly fit

[image]

Comment: I tried nowrap and now the last icon is going away from the screen. Next step I edited the size of the label to be smaller and it fits, but its not centered. See updated in main question

Comment: can you share your icons (svgs)? I tried to reproduce with my own custom svg and I can't I think your svgs might have something in them

Comment: @FernandoBastosGarcía can you also try to add 'size="small"' to your ion-icons?

Comment: You can find my svg in this gallery https://www.flaticon.com/packs/wedding-18

Comment: It looks that putting the no-padding in the columns and the nowrap in the row make the tricks. I even set back the label to its original size. Didnt change the icons size. I will keep the question open few days still before giving the reputation